# should data be up-to-date, when sending a record from datagridview to an editing form?

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

i have a windows form with a **datagridview** control and some input fields. when the form loads it will load about 100 rows to the grid. and these records were fetched from 3 db tables. Keep in mind that the application also must handle optimistic concurrency violations at update. The user double clicks on a record and sends them to the input fields of the form for editing. This is where my problem is.  If this is a busy application, some one might change this record while i'm viewing it. So when i double click to send the record to the input fields for editing, should i re-fetch that record from the database and set the new values to input fields rather than setting with the value that is visible in the **datagridview**?

In this situation what would an industry level application do?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could warn the 2nd user that some 1st user had edited the data you are about to edit/send.
There after you could prompt him to either over write the data with new data or see the edits of the 1st user and then let him decide whether to over write his changes.

Comment: so the old data is sent to editing form, then edit then try to save then the system complaints!

Comment: When the new data is sent to the second user, prompt him that his data is old and here is the new data! Then let him decide whether to over write it or not